# Open 64-bit .accde file in 32-bit version of Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, 64-bit, x86-64

I have created a .accde access file using MS Office 2013 64-bit, but I have to open in other PC that is running a 32-bit version of Access.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not doable.

You might be able to *open* it, but you won't be able to edit or run the VBA code, so if the file depends on that, it'll be completely worthless.

The reason for this is that an `accde` file is a stripped/locked-down version of the original `accdb` file. It includes *only* the compiled version of the VBA code, and this code would have been compiled to target a 64-bit architecture. 64-bit code cannot be run from a 32-bit process, so it will not work when you try to run it in 32-bit Access.

Your only real option would be to reverse-engineer the file, and therefore the compiled VBA code that it contains, such that you could translate it back into VBA. This would *not* be a trivial undertaking, even if you used a tool to help, since decompilation is never perfect.

Comment: Tks. I have opened a ACCDB file on windows 32 bits and created the accde using this operational system.